# How to check if a blob exists through pyspark

Tags: python, blob, databricks

I'm trying to grab a blob storage file into my python code on databricks only if it exists. How can I check if it exists through pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is some method to check if blob exist but from below code you can read it before you will write it.

On the application level, first of all as always in spark applications, you need to grab a spark session:

```
session = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

Then you need to set up an account key:

```
session.conf.set(
    "fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
    "<your-storage-account-access-key>"
)
```

OR SAS token for a container:

```
session.conf.set(
    "fs.azure.sas.<container-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
    "<sas-token>"
)
```

Once an account access key or a SAS is set up you're ready to read/write to Azure blob:

```
sdf = session.read.parquet(
    "wasbs://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<prefix>"
)
```

Though using python you can easliy call the get_blob_reference method to check if blob exist or not.

```
def blob_exists(self):
        container_name = self._create_container()
        blob_name = self._get_blob_reference()

        # Basic
        exists = self.service.exists(container_name, blob_name)  # False
        self.service.create_blob_from_text(container_name, blob_name, u'hello world')
        exists = self.service.exists(container_name, blob_name)  # True

        self.service.delete_container(container_name)
```

You can find the reference here:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/samples/blob/block_blob_usage.py